# django template - for loop over 2 querysets

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am getting 2 querysets from db:

```
all_locations = Locations.objects.all()[:5]
rating = Rating.objects.all()[:5]
return render_to_response('index.html',{'all':all_locations,'rating':rating},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But I am stuck here, not knowing how to loop over these 2 querysets in one loop. this is being wrong:

```
{% if all and rating %}
  {% for every in all and rating  %}
         {{every.locationname}}, {{every.rating_score}}
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Are they of equal length?

Comment: @JasonSperske, yeah, they are of equal length

Comment: btw: it is saying: ``Could not parse the remainder: '[all_locations,bewertung]' from '[all_locations,bewertung]'`` if i do ``for (a,b) in [all_locations,bewertung]``.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `zip(all_locations, rating)`. It will produce a list of tuples. Then you can iterate over them in pairs. Here is an example: ([demo](http://labs.codecademy.com/pNL#%3aworkspace))

```
all_locations = ['ca','ny','fl']
ratings = ['best','great','good']
for (l,r) in zip(all_locations,ratings): 
   print l+':'+r
```

Outputs

```
ca:best
ny:great
fl:good
```

Comment: like this? : ``for (a,b) in list``

Comment: thanks, but i am getting error if i do: ``{% for (loc,bew) in zip(all_locations,bewertung) %}``. ERROR: ``Could not parse the remainder: '(all_locations,bewertung)' from 'zip(all_locations,bewertung)'``

Comment: According to the Django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/ you can't invok zip from within the Django templating language, but you can zip in the views.py and expose the list as a variable to your template.

Answer (score 4):

I have also come across this problem. Now I've fixed it.
what I do is using

```
new=tuple(zip(queryset1,queryset2))  
return render(request, 'template.html', {"n": new}).
```

in view.py.

In template.html, I use three for sentences which are list below.

```
{% for i in n %}

{% for j in i|slice:"0:1" %}

......operate queryset1

{% endfor %}
{% for z in i|slice:"1:2" %}

.....operate queryset2


{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}

It seems this method will fulfill your needs.
```

Comment: Whats the process of doing if they are not equal in length??

Answer (score 1):

this might work:

```
{% with rating|length as range %}
    {% for _ in range %}
        {{ rating[forloop.counter] }}
        {{ location[forloop.counter] }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith %}
```

i'm not sure if `rating|length` will to the job... you might need to add `rating|length|times' with`times` filter defined as:

```
@register.filter(name='times') 
def times(number):
    return range(number)
```

Comment: so i should put it between this? ``{% if all_locations and rating %} .. {% endif %}``